# Docker behind VPN cannot start after downloading TFS container

Tags: docker, containers, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a docker cluster behind a VPN. I have downloaded TFS agent container, and want to connect to our TFS but it cannot connect with an alarm of:

```
Determining matching VSTS agent...
Downloading and installing VSTS agent...
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

It can ping google.But cannot ping public TFS. I would consider this as a network issue but nginx container was pulled and started with success.

```
  docker run \
  -e VSTS_ACCOUNT= xxx \
  -e TFS_HOST= yyy \
  -e VSTS_TOKEN= zzz \
  -it microsoft/vsts-agent
```

also tried this:

```
docker run \
  -e VSTS_ACCOUNT= xxx \
  -e VSTS_AGENT='$(hostname)-agent'\
  -e VSTS_TOKEN= yyy \
  -e TFS_URL= zzz \
  -e VSTS_POOL= eee \
  -e VSTS_WORK='/var/vsts/$VSTS_AGENT' \
  -v /var/vsts:/var/vsts \
  -it microsoft/vsts-agent:ubuntu-14.04
```

Although it is behind VPN, I can access the repo from browser btw.

Comment: what exactly you mean? if it needs certificates, why it worked on my local machine without problem ?

Comment: it is on visualstudio.com, and it does not have any certificates from company

Comment: Try removing the tfs_host and TFS_url parameters.

Comment: it does not help

Comment: Which server do you want to connect? VSTS or On Premise TFS? And which image do you download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems docker shows SSL Handshake issue even if you have network issue. But it showing that connection through curl was OK. This issue was solved by adding IP to whitelist.